# mysql: joining two strings in one variable

Tags: mysql

so I wrote a procedure that should join two strings in one variable and then store it in the DB. the procedure works fine when i run it but it doesn't store the variable in the db. instead it stores it as 0. 
this is the code I used

```
select memFname, memLname into fn, ln from member where memberid = memid;
SET v_name := fn || '  ' || ln ;

insert into profile(memberid, fullName) values (memid, v_name);
```

fn, ln, and v_name are variables of type varchar. memid is a variable of type integer.
am I missing something here?

I'm using a trigger to call the procedure.

Trigger code

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger prof_name
after insert on member
for each row
begin
call profile_fullname(new.memberid);

END $$; 
DELIMITER ;
```

member table structure: 
memberid integer,
memfname varchar,
memlname varchar.

profile table structure:
profid integer,
memberid integer.

Comment: You are using Oracle syntax but your question is tagged mysql.  Please tag it appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `||` operator in MySQL is a logical operator.  You are using it as a concat, which is why I thought you were using Oracle.  As a logical operator, it will convert each argument to a logical expression, which has a value of `0` or `1`.  Obviously, it is converting them to `0`s, which is why you are getting `0` in the table.  The alternative would be `1`, which isn't any more interesting.

The right solution is to use `concat()` instead of `||`.  You can also set the system variable `PIPES_AS_CONCAT` to use `||` as you want to, but that would normally only be set if you were trying to make code portable between databases.

Here are examples:

```
update profile
    set fullName = (select concat(memFname, ' ', memLname) from member m where m.memberid = memid)
    where profile.memberid = memid;
```

If you actually want an insert, it looks something like this:

```
insert into profile(memberid, fullname)
    select memid, concat(memFname, ' ', memLname)
    from member m
    where m.memberid = memid;
```

Comment: It still inserts the fullname value as 0 in the DB

Comment: @Wabbit . . . Edit the question and show the table layout for `profile` and `member`.